# io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 20 second(s)

Tags: java, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I have a service that consumed data from Redis streams every second and sends the data to the client via web socket. Everything worked just fine until two weeks ago (this code has been written two years ago). Since then i'm getting lots of RedisCommandTimeoutException errors. This is the full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Redis command timed out; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 20 second(s)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:70)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceReactiveRedisConnection.lambda$translateException$0(LettuceReactiveRedisConnection.java:293)
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.lambda$onErrorMap$28(Flux.java:7070)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:255)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:134)
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onError(RedisPublisher.java:891)
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$State.onError(RedisPublisher.java:712)
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onError(RedisPublisher.java:357)
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.onError(RedisPublisher.java:797)
at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.doOnError(RedisPublisher.java:793)
at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.completeExceptionally(CommandWrapper.java:128)
at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandExpiryWriter.lambda$potentiallyExpire$0(CommandExpiryWriter.java:175)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandTimeoutException: Command timed out after 20 second(s)
at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createTimeoutException(ExceptionFactory.java:59)
at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandExpiryWriter.lambda$potentiallyExpire$0(CommandExpiryWriter.java:176)
... 8 more
```

This error appears in each subscribed stream at the same time, let's say i have three streams that i'm subscribing to, with names "A", "B" and "C", all of them will have this error at the same time, although i'm using different subscribers for each stream.

Nothing has changed in this service, not in the code and not in the configurations. I looked at the CPU, heap memory, etc. of the service and everything looks fine. I checked AWS Elasticache as well and it seems like there are no problems too (I even talked with AWS support). There is no significant increase in number of streams or opened web sockets.

In addition, i have two other services that write to the Redis streams and they're working great.

I'm using `ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory` class from spring-data-redis library.
This is configurations:

```
@Bean(name = "streamRedisLettuceConnectionFactory")
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    log.info("Connecting to redis with configuration : {} ", chpStreamRedisConfiguration);
    LettuceClientConfiguration configuration = getLettuceClientConfiguration();
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration, configuration);
}

@Bean(name = "streamRedisStandaloneConfiguration")
public RedisStandaloneConfiguration getRedisStandaloneConfiguration() {
    return new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getHost(), chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getPort());
}

@Bean(name = "streamLettuceClientConfiguration")
public LettuceClientConfiguration getLettuceClientConfiguration() {
    return LettucePoolingClientConfiguration.builder()
            .poolConfig(getLettucePoolConfig())
            .commandTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getTimeout()))
            .build();
}

@Bean(name = "streamLettucePoolConfig")
public GenericObjectPoolConfig getLettucePoolConfig() {
    GenericObjectPoolConfig genericObjectPoolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getConnectionPool().getMaxTotal());
    genericObjectPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getConnectionPool().getMaxTotal());
    genericObjectPoolConfig.setMinIdle(chpStreamRedisConfiguration.getConnectionPool().getMinIdle());
    return genericObjectPoolConfig;
}
```

I'm using:
`spring-data-redis:2.3.9.RELEASE`
`lettuce-core:6.1.2.RELEASE`
`spring-boot:5.2.18.RELEASE`

I tried to upgrade lettuce to the latest version (6.2.2) and it didn't help.
I used `io.lettuce.core.protocol` on debug and the only thing i got is this:

```
Completing command LatencyMeteredCommand [type=XREAD, output=StreamReadOutput [output=[], error='Command timed out after 20 second(s)'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand]
```

I prefer not to increase the timeout because 20 seconds is already lot of time.

Comment: There is most likely an error somewhere between the point you invoke a redis command to the time it is actually written out to the connection or in the flow between receiving the message from redis to the point where you retrieve the object in the code. This could be in custom marshal/unmarshal code or any SPI that may be invoked in the command lifecycle etc. Look for detail stack traces and you should find the root cause.